# Inno Setup replace buttons at wpFinished page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to override Next/Cancel buttons on wpFinished page - NextButton should show downloaded file and exit the installator - it's working ok but CancelButton doesn't do nothing - it should close the installator with standard confirm. I wonder it is possible with standard inno events or I need to write own code to exit the application and show the confirm?

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPage = wpFinished then begin
    ShowDownloadedFile();
  end;
  Result := True;
end;


procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall);  
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);  
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Visible := True;  
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There's nothing to cancel at the `wpFinished` page -- everything has already been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, but don't do this at home kids :-)

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode: UINT);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  // if the fake Finish button was clicked...
  if CurPage = wpFinished then
    MsgBox('Welcome to the next installation!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure CancelButtonClickFinishedPage(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // display the "Exit Setup ?" message box and if the user selects "Yes",
  // then exit the process; it is currently the only way how to exit setup
  // process manually
  if ExitSetupMsgBox then
    ExitProcess(0);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonInstall);  
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);  
    WizardForm.CancelButton.Visible := True;
    // bind your own OnClick event for the Cancel button; the original one
    // is already disconnected at this stage
    WizardForm.CancelButton.OnClick := @CancelButtonClickFinishedPage;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper alternative to what you're trying to do is to include a `[Run]` entry like so:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\yourfile.exe; Description: Run my application; Flags: postinstall nowait
```

This will display a checkbox on the `wpFinished` page giving them the choice to run the app or not.